# Why moving eye position will cut (clip) 3d object?

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Why moving eye position, using setLookAtM, will clip the 3d view of my model?
I am moving eye Z position using time.
Please check video and code:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10

import android.opengl.GLES20
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
import android.opengl.Matrix
import android.os.SystemClock
import com.daftar.planetarium.SkyGrid
import com.daftar.planetarium.Square
import com.daftar.planetarium.Triangle
import kotlin.math.cos
import kotlin.math.sin

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
const val COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3


class MyGLRenderer : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private lateinit var mTriangle: Triangle
    private lateinit var mSquare: Square
    private lateinit var mSkyGrid:SkyGrid

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        // initialize a triangle
        mTriangle = Triangle()
        // initialize a square
        mSquare = Square()

        mSkyGrid = SkyGrid()
    }

    private val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(16)

    override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {
        // Redraw background color
        val time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 12400
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0,
                0f,0f,-time/1500f,
                0f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(vPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0)

        val scratch = FloatArray(16)

        // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
        val angle = 0*0.090f * time.toInt()
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0f, 0f, -1.0f)

        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        // Note that the vPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, vPMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0)

        // Draw triangle
//        mTriangle.draw(scratch)

        mSkyGrid.draw(scratch)
    }

    // vPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private val vPMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val projectionMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val viewMatrix = FloatArray(16)

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(unused: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

        val ratio: Float = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 3f, 7f)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipping is related to the projection matrix. The projection matrix specifies a [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). All the geometry which is not in the viewing volume (frustum) is clipped. Therefore, All the geometry which is not in between the near and far plane is clipped:

[image]

The distance between the geometry and the camera has to be stored in the depth buffer. The distances between the near and far plane (normalized device z coordinate) is mapped to the range of a value in the depth buffer.

In your case the distance to the near plane is 3 and the distance to the far plane is 7

> ```java
> Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 3f, 7f);
> ```

You have to increase the distance to the far plane. e.g.:

```java
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 3f, 20f);
```